# how to read adjacent strings

Tags: c++

I am new to programming. Can anyone help me how to do this.
My input file is like this

> The
>
> dog
>
> is
>
> running

I need to get output like this

> The dog
>
> dog is
>
> is running

that is I have to read adjacent word pairs. How do I do this in C++?

Comment: 1. Read all words. 2. Loop through all words except the last. 2a. Inside the loop print word and word+1.

Comment: There are 500 input files of this type in a directory. so I am using getline(fin,s1);

Comment: you should read only one line in your loop.

Comment: I used getline(fin,s1);getline(fin.s2) in a while loop and then concat(s1,s2) function , then my output is like this my dog                    is running..but I need ouput like this my dog   dog is  is running

Comment: If each line is one word, you can make use of an iterator pair constructor of a container to read them, and transform it to output by duplicating the word and adding appropriate newlines and spaces. For that, you have to print the first, transform from (first, last), and then print the last. Something like [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2s1tfB%245). You can do the same for `getline` with a `Line` class that overloads `operator>>`.

Comment: @carleeto: the homework tag is being eliminated, and then, so should these comments.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my novice-C++ approach (I'm only a beginner at C++). I'm sure a more experienced C++ developer will come up with something better :-)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("data.txt");    
    std::string lastWord, thisWord;

    std::getline(file, lastWord);

    while (std::getline(file, thisWord))
    {
        std::cout << lastWord << " " << thisWord << '\n';
        lastWord = thisWord;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Actually, for a beginner this is *really* good. Respect ;)

Comment: @leemes: Thank you :-) I'm not bad at C but there's so much more to learn with C++... especially now with C++11 too. I'm getting there but it is a slow process [for me]!

Answer (score 2):

While I think @dreamlax has shown some nice code, I think I'd do things just a little bit differently:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::string words[2];
    std::ifstream file("data.txt");

    std::getline(file, words[1]);
    for (int current = 0; std::getline(file, words[current]); current ^= 1)
        std::cout << words[current] << ' ' << words[current^1] << "\n";
}
```

This shortens the code a bit (kind of nice) and avoids copying strings unnecessarily (nicer).